# Prettier bracketSpacing not working at all

Tags: javascript, eslint, webstorm, prettier

WebStorm.

**prettier.config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
  printWidth: 80,
  embeddedLanguageFormatting: 'auto',
  jsxBracketSameLine: true,
  tabWidth: 2,
  proseWrap: 'always',
  semi: true,
  bracketLine: false,
  bracketSpacing: true,
};
```

**.eslingrc.json:**

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "react-hooks",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      },
      {
        "usePrettierrc": true
      }
    ],
    "import/no-dynamic-require":"off",
    "global-require": "off",
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "import/no-cycle": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
    "import/no-named-as-default-member": "off",
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
    "no-param-reassign": "off",
    "radix": "off",
    "import/order": "off",
    "no-plusplus": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "no-unused-expressions": "off",
    "array-callback-return": "warn",
    "react/jsx-no-bind": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "consistent-return": "off",
    "new-cap": "off",
    "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
    "react/forbid-prop-types": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "react/no-unused-state": "warn",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-nested-ternary": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": "off",
    "react/sort-comp": "off",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "off",
    "no-return-assign": "warn",
    "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
    "guard-for-in": "warn",
    "no-restricted-syntax": "warn",
    "max-classes-per-file": "off",
    "react/state-in-constructor": "off",
    "react/static-property-placement": "off",
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off",
    "react/no-did-update-set-state": "warn",
    "camelcase": "off",
    "prefer-destructuring": "warn",
    "no-await-in-loop": "warn",
    "no-restricted-globals": "off",
    "no-bitwise": "off",
    "eqeqeq": "warn",
    "no-shadow": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control": "off",
    "react/button-has-type": "off",
    "array-bracket-spacing": ["error", "always"],
    "object-curly-spacing": ["error", "always"]
  }
}
```

[image]

Why??? The `braceSpacing` option is not conspicuous at all, no matter what is specified or what the value is. Any values ​​or if you do not specify the rule at all - requires the absence of spaces. Please help. I tried different versions of Prettier or ESLint.

UPD: It`s not working only for Array

Comment: Are you sure those `array-bracket-spacing` and `object-curly-spacing` rules aren't conflicting with `prettier`?

Comment: @AKX I added these options in hopes of overriding prettier. They work correctly, but now in any spelling "error". But if you remove these rules, prettier does not start working correctly(

Comment: `bracketSpacing` is only for object literals (curly braces) and not arrays. I don't mean to sound all preachy, but you should consider wether its worth the effort. No one in a team of folks agrees on the best formatting, spacing, tabs etc etc. The whole point in prettier is to just pick a way and stick to it and put the conversation to bed.  Hence it has limited config options. https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html. Afterall, it doesn't actually matter, and you'll find yourself getting used the other way.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.